# Run a script on remote server with ssh password or key

Tags: bash, shell, remote-server

I'm trying to run a script on a remote server with either password credentials or .pem key access and I'm getting errors no matter which solution I've found etc.

bash script content:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo fdisk -l


ssh -T -i "~/.ssh/keys/key.pem" ubuntu@host "sudo bash <(wget -qO- http://host.com/do.sh)"
Error: bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or director

ssh user@host.com 'echo "password" | sudo bash <(wget -qO- http://www.host.io/do.sh)'
Error: sudo: a password is required

ssh -t user@host.com "echo password | sudo fdisk -l"
Works but still gives me the password propmt

echo -t pass | ssh user@host "sudo bash <(wget -qO- http://host.com/do.sh)"
echo -tt pass | ssh user@host "sudo bash <(wget -qO- http://host.com/do.sh)"
Error: bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
// And I also get the password prompt

echo -tT pass | ssh user@host "sudo bash <(wget -qO- http://host.com/do.sh)"
Error: sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
       sudo: a password is required
// And I also get the password prompt

// This works but I still get the password propmt
ssh user@host 'echo "password" | sudo -S sudo fdisk -l'
```

These are different variations of the supposed solutions from other places.

What I'm trying to do:

1. Is to run a script from a URL on the remote server while echoing the password to the cmd so I don't get propmt to input the password manually.
2. To be able to do the same thing above with using the .pem key variant also

Answer (score 0):

**For an explanation for commands except the first one**, You can't do stdin-redirect a password to ssh if `ssh` requires interactively. `ssh` only allows manual typing if you use a password.

**Your first error** said that bash can't read a file descriptor. So ssh via `~/.ssh/keys/key.pem` works. To run the shell command on the fly,

```
ssh -T -i "~/.ssh/keys/key.pem" ubuntu@host "curl -fsSL http://host.com/do.sh | sudo bash"
```

Comment: Uh, you can't wrap double quotes like that; you are running `curl` locally, without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Does your script really need to run with sudo??

If not, then try this:

```bash
ssh user@host "curl -s -o do.sh 'http://host.com/do.sh'; source do.sh"
```